# 502 Bad Gateway Error Deploying Django App to GCP App Engine with Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, deployment, gunicorn

I've successfully deployed my Django application to Google Cloud Platform's App Engine, but when trying to access it via the provided URL, I encounter a "502 Bad Gateway" error served by Nginx. Locally, my application runs fine using Waitress (for testing purposes), and I'm able to access it through a browser without any issues.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

- **Environment**: Python 3.11
- **Framework**: Django 4.1
- **WSGI Server for Deployment**: Gunicorn
- **Deployment Platform**: Google Cloud Platform App Engine
- **Error Message**: "502 Bad Gateway nginx"

My `app.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
runtime: python311
service: forecasting-django-app
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT sales_forecasting.wsgi:application

handlers:
- url: /static/
  static_dir: staticfiles/
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

And my project structure:

sales_forecasting/

- forecasting/ (Django app)
- sales_forecasting/ (Django project)
- staticfiles/
- app.yaml
- main.py
- manage.py
- requirements.txt
- results.json

Upon reviewing GCP logs, I noticed an error suggesting that a worker was killed, potentially due to running out of memory: [ERROR] Worker (pid:17) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?

What I've tried so far:

1. Ensuring gunicorn is properly installed and works locally.
2. Checking that static files are correctly configured and collected.

Comment: check your ram resource of server, This log said out memory. what is your number worker?

Comment: @TanThien , there are 8 workers setting up. Do i need only 1 worker ?

I got the server error after my initial page loaded. I believe I am not familiar with how django app deployed on GCP uses memory.

Comment: yes, make it 1 worker for checking. If there aren't errors, decrease the workers from 8 workers. With 8 workers, it mean you have 8 server in a one pod , need x8 memory. Another option is `preload_app = True`, with this configuration, application will deploy on master worker, 8 child worker use from it avoid out memory, but the peformace is lower